# parsing form parameters from raw http requests in java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, text-parsing, http-request-parameters

I'm trying to extract some information from raw HTTP Request messages (like the one below) and store them into instances of the **org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest** (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html) class.

I was able to employ **org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser** class and its method *parseHeader(String value, LineParser parser)* to process (parse + store) the headers, but I don't know how to deal with the parameters passed with the form.

```
POST https://gist.github.com:443/gists HTTP/1.1
Host: gist.github.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en,fr;q=0.8,it-it;q=0.6,it;q=0.4,en-us;q=0.2
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: https://gist.github.com/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------10314229756379422411656878663
Content-Length: 1242

-----------------------------10314229756379422411656878663
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parameter_name"

parameter_value
```

Do you know an utility which can parse the content starting after the header above (i.e. after the first empty line)? What I am interest in collecting are all the pairs <"parameter_name","parameter_value"> present in the request body.

I have already read similar answers/questions such as [Parsing raw HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255622/parsing-raw-http-request) but I did not find anything helpful on the form-data component

Thanks in advance for your help and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is MIME encoded content body. HttpClient is content agnostic and therefore does not provide a means of parsing such content. One can however use [Apache Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html) to do so.

Comment: I tried to do so, but it appears I have to define the content handler, which is not a simple task. 
I hoped for something more similar to what httpclient provides for parsing headers

Comment: @Alby: Mime4J supports both SAX style (event driven) and DOM style (object model) parsing. You can use DefaultMessageBuilder#parseMessage to parse mime content into an object model

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I still cannot vote up, but I accepted your answer). I was able to get the parameter_name with
`DefaultMessageBuilder dmb = new DefaultMessageBuilder();
  AbstractMessage am = (AbstractMessage) dmb.parseMessage(instream);
  Multipart mp = (Multipart) am.getBody();
  List<Entity> es = mp.getBodyParts();
  
  for (int j = 0; j < es.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(es.get(j).getHeader().toString());
  }`