# Regex for HTTP request not working in some occasions

Tags: java, regex, http

I'm making a java server to process HTTP requests using only `Socket` class, since my professor said we couldn't use the HTTP libraries (because the goal is to learn the HTTP...). So, I decided to process the requests using regex. The first thing that happens on the code is that it gets each line of the request and transform it into a single string which I process with patterns. I only need to implement cases for: **GET**, **POST**, **PUT**, **HEAD**, **DELETE**. I'm using the app **Postman**, a Google Chrome extension to test my program. Here are some examples of requests coming from postman after I made it into a single string:

Get:

> GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:15000 Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: no-cache User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36 Postman-Token: dd87e652-2b21-3632-30ad-ace26581d369 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Post without body:

> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:15000 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36 Postman-Token: 8094b5ce-4b3d-cee7-2d10-f5dd2bc6b7b2 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Post with body:

> POST / HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:15000 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 9 Postman-Token: 3fb2f5e0-2df1-5af4-7853-e9de84648dd5 Cache-Control: no-cache Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.101 Safari/537.36 Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Etc...

The pattern I wrote is:

```
    String somethingPattern = "(.*)?";

    String ipPattern = "(((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1?[0-9]?[0-9]))\\.((2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|(1?[0-9]?[0-9]))|"+somethingPattern+")((:)\\d{3,})?"; // regex for ip varying from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 or some string, followed or no by : and a port number 
    String objetoPattern = "([/?a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+)"; // regex for a linux path to a file, including only letters, numbers and -_.

    String connectionPattern = "(connection:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String contentLenPattern = "(content-length:\\s*([0-9]+))?";
    String postmanTokenPattern = "(postman-token:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String cacheControlPattern = "(cache-control:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String originPattern = "(origin:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String userAgentPattern = "(user-agent:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String charsetPattern = "(charset="+somethingPattern+")?";
    String contentTypePattern = "(content-type:\\s*"+somethingPattern+";"+charsetPattern+")?";
    String acceptPattern = "(accept:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String acceptEncodingPattern = "(accept-encoding:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";
    String acceptLanguagePattern = "(accept-language:\\s*"+somethingPattern+")?";


    // (?i) is for the case of coming get, Get, GET... etc...
    String pattern = "^(?i)(get|put|head|post|delete)\\s+?" + objetoPattern + "\\s+?HTTP/1.1\\s+?host:\\s+?" + ipPattern + "\\s+?" + connectionPattern + "\\s+?" + contentLenPattern + "\\s+?" + postmanTokenPattern + "\\s+?" + cacheControlPattern + "\\s+?" + originPattern + "\\s+?" + userAgentPattern + "\\s+?" + contentTypePattern + "\\s+?" + acceptPattern + "\\s+?" + acceptEncodingPattern + "\\s+?" + acceptLanguagePattern + "\\s+?$";
```

The regex is matching and grouping fine for most of the request **except** from **GET**, **HEAD** and a **POST without a body**. I don't know why this is happening. I put a `?` in the end of each pattern just for the case that, for example, a `origin`, `content-length` or something like being not present in the request. But even though it is not matching these cases. The part of the code of the matching is:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(in); // this in is the input string that is the request all joined in a single line string

if(m.find()){
// ......
} else {
  System.out.println("Input didn't match");
}
```

**EDIT**: The part of the code that process the input from the Socket:

```
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String in = "";
        while((msgDoSocket = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            try {
                in += msgDoSocket + " ";
                if(msgDoSocket.isEmpty()){
                    processaInput(in); // this calls the part that process regex
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header lines are separated by newlines, and the header is separated from the body (if present) with 2 consecutive newlines. 
You should use a `Scanner` object as it's using newlines to separate tokens by default, much easier than the `Matcher`. You could simply iterate through those lines. When you got those headerlines, you could slice them by the ':' to form a `Map` instead of a million type of variables to cover all the header key possibilities. Then you could simply check the map key-values to match what you sent.

Also you could use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)/[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to see the raw request by postman.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31600846/4414875) answer using reader and doing the same you want.

Comment: Ok, so how to use the `Scanner` object with the pattern matching? I itarated it using both Scanner and `BufferedReader` but both ended in the "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" as the last line. I think the problem here is more about the regex than reading the input request method